# using a variable in the cursor.execute function()

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-design

I've been trying to come up with a basic menu based Python program for database management as a project. However, I got stuck when it came to using the cursor.execute() function - with a variable in the parameter.
Here's the code (pardon my disorderliness):

```
elif choose == 4:
cursor = convar.cursor()
con = True
name = str(input("Enter name of table: "))
str1 = 'create table {} '.format(name)
str2 = ''
print("Enter table details. ")
con = True
str2 = ''
while con == True:
    col = str(input("Enter name of column: "))
    typ = str(input("Enter data type of column: "))

    command = '{} {}(255)'.format(col, typ)
    str2 = str2 + command 
    
    conti = str(input("Do you wish to create more columns? "))
    if conti == 'Yes' or conti == 'yes':
        str2 = str2 + ', '
    elif conti == 'no' or conti == 'No':
        str2 = '(' + str2 + ')'
        con = False
    else:
        pass

cursor.execute ('create table {} {}'.format(name, str2))
```

This portion of the code aims to create  table, while allowing the user to specify the name of the table, and the data types of the columns
this is done by storing all of the users inputs as a string, and at the end, using the string with the cursor.execute() function.

But whenever i run this code, i get an error.
I'm not sure if the error is because of incorrect syntax, or because one *cannot use a variable* in cursor.execute()

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: First of all, what error are you getting? Please send your error messages and put it on your question.

Comment: Save your `'create table {} {}'.format(name, str2)` into a variable, get the query, execute it in CLI and look at syntax errors.

Comment: PS. `command = '{} {}(255)'.format(col, typ)` is obviously errorneous. Such length value is applicable to string types only.